# How to pass multiple parameters to callSingle karate on karate-config.js

Tags: karate

I have a .feature file that will receive argument from another feature file as __arg to generate token for oAuth

```
 Given url urlRefreshToken
 Given def json = __arg
 And header Content-Type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
 And request json
 * header Authorization = 'Bearer' + __arg.refresh_token
 When method POST
 Then status 200
 * def bearer = 'Bearer ' + response.access_token
```

I am trying to centralise the token generation for only one time on `karate-config.js`. However I cannot seem to be able to use karate.callSingle() with passed parameters.

I use the feature file to generate token on other feature files as:

```
* def getToken = call read('classpath:features/Utils/GetToken.feature') refreshTokenRaymond
* header Authorization = getToken.bearer
```

I am trying to invoke the feature file for generating token on `karate-config.js` to no avail. I tried to pass in the additional parameter like this on `karate-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    baseUrl: 'url',
    urlRefreshToken: 'url',
    refreshToken: '{refreshToken: refreshToken}'
  };
var token = karate.callSingle('classpath:features/Utils/GetToken.feature', [config, config.refreshToken])
```

I wonder if it is possible to pass multiple parameter to `karate.callSingle()` called from `karate-config.js`?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`call` and `karate.callSingle()` take only one argument, but you can easily create a new JSON out of other JSONs. Actually since you seem to be passing `config` as the argument - you can easily access `config.refreshToken` as `__arg.refreshToken`.

Your code is very confusing - but hope that this hint is what gets you on your way:

```
Given def json = __arg.refreshToken
```

If you need to create a JSON out of other data - I think you already know how to do that:

```
var temp = { config: config, refreshToken: refreshToken };
var token = karate.callSingle('classpath:features/Utils/GetToken.feature', temp);
```